# Writing 32 bit integers to sequential MODBUS holding registers

Tags: vb.net, modbus

I have a general question here. I have 32 bit integers that I want to write to sequential MODBUS registers which I will later read back. I understand holding registers are 16 bit so I need to read/write the 32 bit integer from/to two consecutive MODBUS holding registers.

My question is how do I write sequentially without them interfering with each other?

The code I am using is vb.net.

When I write 32 bit integers to sequential MODBUS addresses I get incorrect values read back from the MODBUS registers.

[image: 32 bit values to registers]

Is there a way to use the byte order or word order so that holding registers will share data that will allow me to read/write 32 bit integers from/to holding registers without any issues?

Thank you.

Comment: Looking at your diagram, isn't Value 2 overwriting Value 1 in the MODBUS Holding Register 1? I'd think you'd need 4 registers, not 3.

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to store two different values in one register (register 1 holds part of value 1 and part of value 2). You cannot do this, when writing the second value you will overwrite part of the first.

> I understand holding registers are 16 bit so I need to read/write the 32 bit integer from/to two consecutive MODBUS holding registers.

Well you need two 16 bit registers to write the data. The Modbus spec says nothing about 32 bit values, so how you do this is up to you. If you want to write the first 16 bits in register 0 and the second in register 100 then that will work (but might not be easy for others to understand!).

Generally I would expect that a 32 bit value would be written across two adjacent registers. So, in your example the first value could be written to registers 0 and 1, with the second in registers 2 and 3.

> I want to write to sequential MODBUS registers

When dealing with 32 bit values you need two 16-bit registers per value. So I would take "sequential" to mean starting every second register (e.g. 0, 2, 4, 6).

One thing to note is that, because the Spec does not cover storing 32 bit values, you should be clear on the [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) in use. For example, when storing 0x11223344 do you store 0x1122 in register 0 and 0x3344 in register 1, or do the opposite? There is no right answer but it's important that you document the approach your program uses (because the spec does not provide any guidance and both orders are used!).